# ¿Cómo buscar enlaces en una página y generar una tabla con ellos?

Tags: r

Estoy realizando un código en R de análisis de datos de paginas HTML y XML y tengo que analizar el contenido de la web, buscando todos los enlaces (que en HTML se etiquetan como “a”), buscando el texto del enlace, así como la URL. Además tengo que generar una tabla con cada enlace encontrado, indicando el texto que acompaña el enlace, y el número de veces que aparece un enlace con ese mismo objetivo.

Lo que tengo hecho es lo siguiente: he conseguido el texto de los enlaces y su URL por separado, ¿como creo la tabla con esos enlaces y su texto y el número de veces que aparece? me sale que `enlaces1` tiene longitud 165 y enlaces 2 tiene longitud 164 y no sabría como hacerlo.

¿Lo que llevo hecho estaría bien?

```
link_url <- "https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki"
fileUrl <- read_html(GET(link_url))
fileUrl

datos <- htmlParse(fileUrl)
datos

enlaces1 <- xpathSApply( doc  = datos
                         , path = "//a"
                         , fun = xmlValue
)
enlaces1

enlaces2 <- xpathSApply( doc  = datos
                        , path = "//a/@href"
)
enlaces2
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo has diagnosticado muy bien, lo que ocurre es que en la página hay un `a` sin `href`, y como buscas de forma independiente los dos elementos ocurre esto:

```
length(enlaces1) == length(enlaces2)
[1] FALSE
```

Lo que si puedes hacer, es iterar sobre los nodos `a` y obtener sus atributos, por lo que siempre tendrías la misma cantidad de elementos, tengan o no el atributo `href`, vamos a usar para esto `rvest`:

```
link_url <- "https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki"
doc <- read_html(link_url)

a_nodes <- html_nodes(doc, "a")
titulos <- html_text(a_nodes)
hrefs <- html_attr(a_nodes, "href")

df <- data.frame(titulos, hrefs)
head(df)

                        titulos                                                                        hrefs
1                                                                                                       <NA>
2            Jump to navigation                                                                     #mw-head
3                Jump to search                                                                 #searchInput
4                               /wiki/File:Wikimedia_Hackathon_Prague_2019_-_Group_Photo_-_CLK_-_cropped.jpg
5                               /wiki/File:Wikimedia_Hackathon_Prague_2019_-_Group_Photo_-_CLK_-_cropped.jpg
6 tens of thousands of websites                               /wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Sites_using_MediaWiki
```

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias! Una pregunta, ¿como podria poner en la tabla el número de veces que aparece un enlace con ese mismo objetivo? Osea, el resultado final tiene que ser una tabla con la URL de los enlaces, El texto de los enlaces, el numero de veces que aparece cada enlace con ese mismo objetivo y el estado de cada enlace

Comment: Te sugiero que hagas otra pregunta planteando esto ya que se desvía mucho de lo planteado aquí.